# How do i convert a Raw Data in python Dictionary

Tags: python, flask

Request body when processed by flask API looses json and becomes string.
I have a Flask API which works fines, I wanted to enhance the feature of the app, so i came across a situation where i would need to pass `json body` within the request body like this.

Request Body:

```
{
    "upload_to": "catalog",
    "compile": [
        "brfc"
    ],
    "extra_profiles": {},
    "config": {{test_config}},
    "bbox": "52.2,13.784,2.61,3.5731",
    "hrn_name": "test",
    "app_name": "BJsKNqMsXul",
    "user_name": "a7f53a07d",
    "project": "od",
    "brfc_tag": "",
    "dynamodb_table": "brf"
}
```

test_config:

```
{
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
}
```

The problem is the `test_config` when processed by flask it becomes like this, i.e a invalid json, and the other jobs dependant on it fails,

P.S i am noob and new to all this

```
{'title': 'Sample Konfabulator Widget', 'name': 'main_window', 'width': '500', 'height': '500'}
```

Update: This was not a proper json to begin with, which caused issue in converting it to python dict.

Comment: Show the code where you're passing `test_config`

Comment: so i am using postman app, `test_config` is a env variable, and its  shared as above, just below `request_body`

Comment: What you're showing looks like the python representation of a dictionary, which is what JSON gets turn into. Why is it that leads you to believe that it's invalid?

Comment: JSON is a string.  That's the whole point.  Everything you are showing up there are objects.  The purpose of JSON is to convert objects to strings so they can be sent over sockets, then convert back to an object at the other end.   You just need to figure out which one you need where.

Comment: what little knowledge i have of json is it requires double quotes and not single. i.e the request becomes invalid because of single quotes, or atleast the app i was sending this to only takes double quotes,  so i needed to convert this dict into a proper double quoted one for it to make it work.

Comment: Update: This was not a proper json to begin with, which caused issue in converting it to python dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with python converting json to single quotes, my solution was as follows

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(JSONLINKHERE) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

But its difficult to actually help when you havent shown code

Also

Have you read [Testing JSON APIs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/#testing-json-apis) on the Flask API Docs